# Android Studio Virtual android device blinking

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

I want to set up android studio's android emulator for React Native and I have a problem with the emulator. I read that it is a problem with resizing. That emulator wants to resize an android window. But I can not find a solution to that.
[image: my problem]